# how to remove a string element from the list if it is already there in another string element?

Tags: python

I want to keep a term which is longest in list element.
Input:
List1=['this','is','to','ask','this question']

Expected output:
List1=['is','to','ask','this question']

Comment: It is unclear what your expexted output is. 
You said you want to keep the longest element in a list, but your expected output contains all of the original list elements except the first.

Comment: `is` is also part of `this`. Why don't you remove `is`?

Comment: I am looking for the complete word which is separated by space

Comment: what have you tried so far,  where are you stuck ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you want to remove "this" because it's a substring of "this question". You're choosing to remove "this" and not "is" because "this" is longer than "is" right?

I would first sorted this list by length of the strings, then double for loop (i and j) to see if i is in j, then remove the last occurrence, because it is the longest.

If you confirm, that my assumption was right I'll try to code it.

**EDIT :**
Since you confirmed my assumption, here's the code :

```
List1=['this','is','to','ask','this question']

def removeSubString(myList):
    sortedList = sorted(myList, key=lambda x: len(x))
    for i in range(len(sortedList), -1, -1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(sortedList)):
            if sortedList[i] in sortedList[j]:  
                 myList.remove(sortedList[i])
                 return myList
    return myList
print(removeSubString(List1))
```

Comment: That's more of a comment.

Comment: I believe they want to remove `this` because it is already part of `this question`...

Comment: yes, you are assumption is right

Comment: "I am looking for the complete word which is separated by space", says the OP. Your code does not do what the OP wants.